# How to switchTo a frame when the body tag is hidden by style="overflow: hidden;"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

In the PeopleSoft page if I click on the lookup it pops up a new widget, I need to select one of the options.

The DOM has been designed in a way which has "style="overflow: hidden;"" in the body tag, with the below xpath I am able to identify the frame in google chrome, however, I couldn't switch to the frame and click on the option I need to select

HTML of the iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="ptModFrame_2" name="ptModFrame_2" src="https://*******:8560/psc/umcssi2/EMPLOYEE/SA/c/SSR_PROG_ENRL.SSR_APT_REQ_RUNCNT.GBL?ICType=Panel&amp;ICElementNum=0&amp;ICStateNum=7&amp;ICResubmit=1&amp;ICAJAX=1&amp;" style="width: 514px; height: 350px;"></iframe>
```

I tried with the below xpath to switch to the frame:

Xpath to switch to frame: `//div[@id='pt_modals']/div[2]/div/div[2]/iframe[contains(@src,'https://*******')]`

Xpath to select the option after switching:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")).click();
```

Note: I also tried javascript executor.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")));
```

I have just frame the same DOM,

```
<body class="PSPAGE" id="ptifrmtemplate" style="overflow: hidden;"><div id="ptpopupmask" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I expect that it should click but it is not switching to the frame in first place.

Comment: Share html with the frame and your code

Comment: This DOM is quite big, can I share the format

Comment: You don't need to share the entire DOM, perhaps the HTML covering the `<iframe>` / `<frame>` tag and the desired element along with it's parent tag will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch to the desired `<iframe>` so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'ptModFrame_') and contains(@src, 'psc/umcssi2/EMPLOYEE/SA/c/SSR_PROG_ENRL.SSR_APT_REQ_RUNCNT.GBL')]")));
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='ptModFrame_'][src*='psc/umcssi2/EMPLOYEE/SA/c/SSR_PROG_ENRL.SSR_APT_REQ_RUNCNT.GBL']")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait frame using `WebDriverWait`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("ptModFrame_2")));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]"))).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it also works after switching to the default content, driver.switchTo().defaultContent();